# how to move an element outside a div with overflow with transform translate property?

Tags: css

I want to move an element outside a div with overflow with the CSS property transform translate

How can I get the same result that the example "without overflow" without
`position: fixed`?

https://jsfiddle.net/to50hf3a/

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  height: 80vh;
}

.parent {
  background: #000;
  width: 10rem;
  height: 5rem;
}

.child {
  background: #ccc;
  width: 5rem;
  height: 3rem;
  transform: translate(6rem, 3rem);
}

.child-fixed {
  position: fixed;
}

.overflow {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
  <div class="main">
  <p>without overflow</p>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>

  <p>with overflow</p>
  <div class="parent overflow">
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>

  <p>with overflow and fixed</p>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child child-fixed"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The only solution a found is to use `position: fixed` but it doesn't work well in a page that can scroll too.

Comment: What is your desired result?

Comment: Like in the example "with overflow and fixed", I want the child goes outside the parent div rather than enlarge and be stuck in it https://imgur.com/k9SiQLF

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code snippet:

CSS:

```
.parent {
    background: #000;
    width: 10rem;
    height: 5rem;
}

.overflow {
    overflow: auto;
}

.child {
    background: #ccc;
    width: 5rem;
    height: 3rem;
    transform: translate(6rem, 3rem);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="parent overflow">
    <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is the div parent must have an overflow, I put the first example for showing what the result I need looks like